# Saving value from 2nd activity to 1st without losing the updated data

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-intent

This app has 2 activities. The main activity shows 4 images as image buttons. When user gets into the form page, user can edit the information of the images. However the info does not save when I edit another image and then return to the first image.
Any help to this would be very appreciated !

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to retrieve an updated data from an activity than easiest solution is to create any class to save constants and update that constants while editing your data and when you want an updated data just call that constant variables from that class.